# Tilde ~ not referring to home

Tags: apache2, home-directory, ssl, navigation

I am getting the error

> SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/~/joebloggs/somesite_com.crt'  does not exist or is empty

Due to the following line written in default-ssl.conf

> SSLCertificateChainFile ~/joebloggs/somesite_com.crt

In order to refer to the file home/joebloggs/joebloggs/somesite_com.crt

I've also used ../ to try and go up a directory when attempting to create a relative address to the crt, but this fails also. Anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: Use of ~ is ambiguous and I highly advise you use the full path in scripts and similar. In this case, in the best case scenario, apache runs as www-data  and there is no /home/www-data .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) referring to one's `$HOME` directory is a `bash` (and other shells') feature.

Apache does not support this feature.

You must specify the file as `/home/joebloggs/joebloggs/somesite_com.crt`

Comment: Agreed but I would add ~ is ambiguous and should not be used in scripts or configuration files. Even if it were supported by Apache, on Ubuntu Apache runs as www-data and there is no /home/www-data and even if there were the certificate is not there, it is in /home/joebloggs

Answer (score 0):

Apache uses the `~` to turn on "extended regular expression" evaluation in directives like Directory.  Someone should have mentioned this I think.

For example ([from manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files)):

```
<Directory ~ "^/www/.*/[0-9]{3}">
```